# Missing Guided Tours - Joomla 5

Tags: joomla-5.x, guidedtour

I just noticed that one of my J5 test sites is missing the Guided Tours listbox in the header.  Did a reinstall of core files, checked the plugin was enabled, but still no Guided Tours.  Any pointers to what's missing appreciated.

[image: Screen shot of header and plugins]

This test site was originally installed from RC version release so it may be the issue.  Was just thinking if anyone knows how to get it up and visible then it may help others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guided Tours functionality needs:

- Plugin: **System - Guided Tours Plugin** (type: system, element: guidedtours)
- Admin Module: **Guided Tours** (module type: Guided Tours)

Could you check if you have published that Admin Module, and in the Module Position `status`?

Comment: Ahh that's it, the admin module wasn't enabled.  Thanks pe7er.